# Derivative of the solutions by parameter

Tags: equation-solving

```
P0 = 0.1;
K = 1000;
Quiet[sol = Solve[{K*P*L == PL, P0 == P + PL, r*P0 == L + PL}, {P, L,PL}][[1]]];
complex = PL /. sol;
Plot[complex, {r, 0.1, 2}]
```

How can I make the solution into a function of parameter `r` in order to get the derivative of the solution, `D[complex[r],r]`?

Comment: Are you just trying to take the derivative of complex?  If so D[complex,r] is what you are looking for

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
 2)[`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking 
the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system 
is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to 
accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, 
[`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Answer (score 4):

You can do it nicely by defining a function `complex`

```
Clear[complex];
complex[x_] := PL /. sol /. r -> x;
Plot[{complex[r], Hold[Evaluate@D[complex[r], r]]} // Release, {r,0.1, 2}]
```

[image]

Otherwise as mentioned in the comment your definition of complex can also be used!

```
Clear[complex];
complex = PL /. sol;
Plot[{complex, Hold[Evaluate@D[complex, r]]} // Release, {r, 0.1, 2}]
```

In the mean time don't forget to notice the `Hold` issue with the `Plot` command. To perform symbolic operations (e.g Differentiation) inside `Plot` you need to use `Hold` as `Plot` replaces the function variable with numeric arguments and thus can result into wrong result for the inner symbolic operation.

Answer (score 1):

Using your definitions, you can simply write:

```
Plot[Evaluate@{complex, D[complex, r]}, {r, 0.1, 2}]
```

The `Evaluate` makes sure that `D[complex, r]` gets evaluated and the expression for the derivative is passed to `Plot`.